# Virtual String Tree 4.8.7 HeaderDblClick Event without function?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I just tried to use the event **OnHeaderDblClick** of the VirtualStringTree Component (Version 4.8.7) Is it possible, that this event is not working?

Or is there some option that I need to set to get it to work?

Comment: The event works OK for me, but I'm using VT 5.0 BTW AFAIK you don't have to set any options for it to work...

Comment: is 5.0 released yet? When I look into VirtualTrees.pas the function DoHeaderDblClick is nowhere being called. Is that different in 5.0?

Comment: I'm not sure it is officially released, I pulled from SVN few months ago. The `DoHeaderDblClick` is called from `TVirtualTreeColumns.HandleClick` in 5.0.

Comment: Check that you have set `coAllowClick` option in the `TVirtualTreeColumn.Options`.

Comment: I checked coAllowClick, but it is already enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it cannot work. Mike forgot to call the `TBaseVirtualTree.DoHeaderDblClick` what fires the `OnHeaderDblClick` in [VirtualTreeView version 4.8.7](http://virtual-treeview.googlecode.com/svn/branches/4.8/Source/VirtualTrees.pas).

It is fixed in [VirtualTreeView version 5.0.0](http://virtual-treeview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source/VirtualTrees.pas) as [ain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/723693/ain) mentioned in `TVirtualTreeColumns.HandleClick` method.